# intents putString putData differences

Tags: android, android-intent, communication, put

What are the main differences between putString and putData when used with Intents to pass information from one activity to another.   I often see the same two methods used in the same way in many of the code samples I have seen.  and what are the advantages of one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you get all information about intents :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html